# Issues approving transactions after updating parity signer

Tags: polkadot-js, wallet

After a year of not using my Parity Signer, I attempted to approve a transaction using it. Initially, the signer displayed an error upon scanning the transaction QR code. In response, I updated the app assuming it needed the update. After updating, I successfully restored the Parity Signer using the mnemonic phrase.

However, I'm encountering a new problem: when I try to sign a transaction, I'm faced with the message "Transaction author public key not found." I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue. I appreciate any assistance or advice. Thank you.

Comment: There was an Issue created on the parity-signer repo if it can help https://github.com/paritytech/parity-signer/issues/1842

Answer (score 1):

`Transaction author public key not found` error indicates that Vault does not have the corresponding key to sign the transaction.

> I have recovered the parity signer with the n-monic phrase

You also need to recover keys that you used for signing.

In case you used custom derivations to create keys on the previous Signer, you need to re-create those keys with the same derivation paths.

But I would assume you didn't create any custom keys. There is an issue: different Signer version have different rules for creating default keys (unfortunately).
So depending on the Signer version you used before, default keys might be either:

- `//<network>` - i.e. `//polkadot` for polkadot
- - empty derivation path

Try to create those keys and see if that helps.

> the signer was giving me an error after scanning the QR from the transaction

Was there an error message? I can only assume it was about outdated metadata. In this case, you need to update it from https://metadata.parity.io/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pavel. Would it be the same default keys for Centrifuge?

Comment: @user4594 yes, for Centrifuge it would be `//centrifuge`. Don't forget to add network specs to the Signer first. https://metadata.novasama.io/?tab=0#/centrifuge

Comment: All done, thanks for your help